# Limit of absolute difference

Tags: calculus, limits, optimization

So let's say I know that I have 2 real functions $a_n(x)$ and $a_0(x)$, and both functions are greater than zero for any $x$. $a_0(x)$ represents an optimal solution and $a_n(x)$ represents a solution for a given order $n$. But we know that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |\sqrt{a_n(x)} - \sqrt{a_0(x)}| = 0$$

The above condition is true for any $x$. From the above condition, can we also conclude that $|a_n(x) - a_0(x)| = 0$ as $n \to \infty$? My initial answer is yes; if the difference of square roots converge to zero, then the difference of the arguments of the square roots must also converge to zero.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sqrt{a_n(x)} - \sqrt{a_0(x)}\right| = 0\iff
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{a_n(x)} = \sqrt{a_0(x)}\implies$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{a_n(x)})^2 = (\sqrt{a_0(x)} )^2 = a_0(x).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! So what property did you use to remove the absolute value (going from step 1 to step 2)?

Comment: @JohnnyQue, is a consequence of the definition of limit: $|x_n-l|<\epsilon\iff ||x_n-l| -0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Hmm,...sorry, not following. If there a formal name for this property? Can you direct me to a reference?

Comment: @JohnnyQue, no formal name because is elementary. You have the equivalence between the two conditions because $|x_n−l| = ||x_n−l|−0|$.

Comment: Still not seeing it, lol. Sorry. In your response, it looks like you essentially removed the absolute values and applied the sum property: $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a_0}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{a_n} - \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{a_0} = \lim \sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{a_0}$.

Comment: @JohnnyQue, write the definitions of $\lim x_n = l$ and $\lim|x_n - l| = 0$.

Comment: Ah, now I see! Thanks for being patient with me, lol :)